# Count the affected rows on insert

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud, rows-affected

I'm trying to get the affected rows on insert. I've seen some solution on how to do it but I don't know how to apply it on my code. I'm using spring boot and I haven't mastered it yet. This is my sample code:

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_table")
public class TestTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface TestTableRepository extends CrudRepository<TestTable, Long> {

}
```

Service:

```
public interface TestTableService {
    public void saveOrUpdate(TestTable testTable);
}
```

Service Impl:

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(TestTable testTable) {
    testTableRepository.save(testTable);
}
```

There are some unique rows so I need to know if it inserted or not.

Hoping you could help me. Thank you

Comment: Can you please include the `TestTable`?

Comment: @Nikhil Already added it!

Comment: Assume your table in DB has set the unique constraint on the column whose value is supposed to be unique.  If it executes without error ,then 1 record is inserted. If there is exception thrown , then 0 records are inserted.

Comment: As Ken said, when you `save` (updates are also done with `save`) you are sending an `Entity` with the corresponding `id` (aka Primary key). So, that particular record/row will be affected. The `save` method returns the Entity, if you need to see what it has returned. [See docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-)